# Axios is not sending cookies even with withCredentials:true

Tags: node.js, http, axios, xmlhttprequest, nuxt.js

i have a problem with my node.js nuxtjs app. I am sending requests with axios to api and on login request i get cookie normally. Everything works with recieving cookie from server, but when i GET another page, cookie isnt sending with it. Here are my OPTIONS on nodejs:

```
let options = { credentials: true, origin: "http://localhost:3000" };

app.use(cors(options))
```

Here is axios request:

```
export default async function ({ store, redirect }) {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/test', {
      withCredentials: true,
      credentials: 'include',
      allowCredentials: true,
    })
    console.error(res)
    store.commit('setAccess', res.data.access)
  } catch {
    return redirect('/register')
  }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Which of the two hosts that you show is setting the cookie?

Comment: The server which is on localhost:5000. I think i realised what i ve done wrong. I placed that request in nuxt middleware, but nuzt middleware isnt browser therefore it does not send cookies.

Comment: For server-side use of axios, you can get a cookie jar to use with Axios to preserve cookies.  See https://github.com/3846masa/axios-cookiejar-support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To justify my mistake. I thought that nuxtjs middleware is running on client, which is not true. So cookie was not sent. I solved it by redirecting to auth page (which can be running some nice spinning wheel) and the submiting the refresh token to server and getting new one.

Thanks for your time and ideas !